# Making scenes in a game without javafx

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make something that when the first scene is done, it moves onto the next scene. I don't use javafx, and I do not plan to use it because I am too lazy to try and download anything else or learn a completely new programming language. I want to know a way to make my character go onto the next scene without using javafx, simply because I am lazy. I may learn it another time but for now I am trying to learn the basics of coding in java, especially when it comes to video games, as I do plan on making games as I become more experienced. I am also too lazy to modify my code unless if it is something minor or something that will actually make things work.

My Code:

```
    
    Player player;
    public ArrayList<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Spike> spikes = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<SpawnPoint> spawnpoints = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<BackgroundWall> backgroundwalls = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<TextThing> textthings = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Timer gameTimer;
    
    public int x = 600;
    public int y = 500;
    
    public int textx = 200;
    public int texty = 300;
    
    public boolean Stage1 = true;
    public boolean Stage2 = false;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        
        player = new Player(x, y, this);
        
        makeObjects1();
        
        gameTimer = new Timer();
        gameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            
            public void run() {
                player.set();
                repaint();
            }
            
        }, 0, 17);
    }
    
    public void makeObjects1() {
        for(int i = 100; i < 1900; i += 100) {
            walls.add(new Wall(i, 700));
        }
        for(int i = 200; i < 700 ; i += 100) {
            walls.add(new Wall(100, i));
        }
        for(int i = 200; i < 500 ; i += 100) {
            walls.add(new Wall(1100, i));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            walls.add(new Wall(i, 100));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 700));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 600));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 500));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 400));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 300));
        }
        for(int i = 100; i < 1200; i += 100) {
            backgroundwalls.add(new BackgroundWall(i, 200));
        }
        
        spikes.add(new Spike(1100, 500));
        spawnpoints.add(new SpawnPoint(x, y));
        textthings.add(new TextThing(textx, texty));
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        
        Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(player.keyDown) {
            player.height = 100;
        }
        if(player.keyReleasedDown) {
            player.height = 200;
        }
    }
```

My coding works btw, it's just that all my attempts in trying to code scenes without javafx failed miserably. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using Swing, then don't use `java.util.Timer` to update your state, use a Swing `Timer`.  In your context, a "scene" is a virtual concept, you will want to devise structures which decouple the "engine" from the "scenes" in such away as the engine doesn't care how the scene is implemented.  When the "scene" determines the the user has "exited" it, then the engine can coordinate with some kind of controller to bring the next scene up - how this is gets done will all come down to you

Comment: Exactly what I have been trying to do but it ain't helping. I just want maybe a tool, variable, or even a set of code that will allow me to get off my feet. That's it. @MadProgrammer